# Adding path to file containing photo on QT form using QGIS/PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, qt

I have just designed my first QT form.

I have a spatial table in PostgreSQL, loaded into QGIS, I have set the "photo_link" column to be "photo" in the fields/widget section of the layer's properties.  When I use the "drag and drop designer " as the layer's attribute editor, I get the expected file picker dialog and button and it all works, I see the photo above it. So I create my form in QT designer and add a "WebView" and associate it with the "photo_link" field.  I get the frame where the photo will appear and when there is already a path to the photo, it appears on the form as expected.

How do I add the path to the photo for a record where the column is null?

There is no picker mechanism on the form.  I can drag and drop a file onto the form and it displays the photo, but pressing OK and saving the edits doesn't save the path to the photo.  So how do you do it, I'm sure its something simple I've missed.